# Implicit change of path of contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, multivalued-functions

I want to compute a contour integral say: $\oint_{C_z} \frac{dz}{S(z)-a}$ or $\oint_{C_z} g(S(z))\,dz$. The problem is that I don't have an explicit form for S(z); rather I have the implicit equation $z=f(S)$. $f(S)$ turns out to be a multivalued function with branch cuts (in my case $f(S)$ involves arctan and square roots). I wanted to calculate the integral instead as:
$\oint_{C_S} g(S(z))\frac{\partial z}{\partial S} \,dS $
since it seems much simpler (and actually doable). 
**Questions**: How limited is the implicit function theorem in this case?Are there any theorems on how the path should be mapped? How do I deal with branch cuts that possibly arise on the path? **Can the integral be computed without explicitly knowing the path in $S$ coordinates?**

EDIT: As pointed out below, the question boils down to whether the contour in $S$ is closed (or how to make it a closed one) and how to apply the residue theorem (or whether it is possible or not).

Comment: if C is a closed contour, then you can use the Cauchy integral formula, and all you need to know are the singularities i.e. where $S(z) = a$

Comment: Assuming C_S is closed (which doesn't seem obvious to me) there's still the problem on whether the poles of the function of S lie inside the new contour and how many times the new contour goes around them.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues here. When you know the path $C_S$ in $S$ space, say parametrized as $S(t)$, $0\leq t\leq 1$ then $z(t)=f(S(t))$ and $dz=f'(S(t))S'(t)dt$ so you may insert in e.g. your first contour integral to get

$$ \oint_{C_z} \frac{dz}{S(z)-a}= \int_0^1 \frac{f'(S(t)) S'(t) dt}{S(t) -a} = \int_{C_S} \frac{f'(S)dS}{S-a}$$ where $C_S$ is the path in $S$-space. When $f$ is 'multi-valued' I suspect that $C_S$ need  not be closed (even though your contour $C_z$ is). So be careful if you want to apply e.g. a residue theorem. Due to singularities the integral in $S$ form may also pick up residues when changing contour so it is likely necessary to know more about the contour than just the end-points, say.
There should be no branch cuts on the contours so you will also need to do analytic continuation along the path (like e.g. the logarithmic 'spiral' if you want to integrate $\log z$ when winding around zero [no cut!]).

As long as derivatives are bounded away from zero and infinity I don't think you have to worry about the implicit function theorem?

Comment: That's my problem actually: whether it is possible to apply the residue theorem to the new integral without knowing the contours explicitly given the residue theorem could be applied to the original integral. I was thinking if there might be some way to extend and close the contour in order to be able to apply the residue theorem. Such as in the integral: $\oint \frac{z^{\frac{1}{2}}}{z+1}dz$ where usually the keyhole contour is used but instead we could "extend" the original path to twice its lenght to go to the other branch without twisting and so getting the other -1 pole in the next branch

Comment: I am pretty sure you must know the contours if you want to apply a residue theorem. For your example I think the point with the keyhole contour is that it allows you to calculate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+t}dt$ (which pops out because of the cut). If you indeed go twice around but you will get zero because you get the same contribution twice with opposite signs. It can also be seen through the covering map $z=w^2$, $dz = 2w dw$. When you go around twice the integral is the same as $\oint \frac{w\; 2w \;dw}{1+w^2}=0$. All this depends upon your ultimate goal?